# Problems with regex applied to a specific string in Python, but it works OK "everywhere" else

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I created a regex to parse two floating point numbers and a `*` symbol between them using Python. As I am completely new to both I've tried basic online guides on using `re` library and regex itself. I came up with `((\d+)?(\.?)\d+)\*((\d+)?(\.?)\d+)` which works fine [here](https://regex101.com/) even for the string in question, `2+21.0*2*2`.

But if I use this expression and string in Python like so
`m = re.match(r"((\d+)?(\.?)\d+)\*((\d+)?(\.?)\d+)", "2+21.0*2*2")`
it gives me "None" object. I do not see any obvious problems, any ideas why it does not work?

Comment: @alexhall `\d+` says there should be a digit or more, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

regex101.com finds the match `21.0*2` in the string `2+21.0*2*2`. `re.match` doesn't because `match` always has to include the start of the string. Using `re.search` instead works.

Answer (score 0):

As [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) says regarding `re.match`:

> If zero or more characters at the beginning of string match the
>   regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object.
>   Return None if the string does not match the pattern

regex101 show that there is match starting at first digit of 21. You should use `re.search` instead:

```
import re
m = re.search(r"((\d+)?(\.?)\d+)\*((\d+)?(\.?)\d+)", "2+21.0*2*2")
print(m is None)  # False
```